# How do i turn user input into upper case in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, discord

Hey this should be an easy question I was wondering how and if i could possibly make this if statement check for "hello" regardless if it's written hello, HELLO, heLLO ect. this is my code here don't worry all the other variables are being taken care of by another library (discord's to be exact) Thanks

```
bot.on('message', function(message){
  if(message.content == "hello")
  {
    message.reply("hello");
  }
```

Comment: Guess people do not read documentation any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript you can use `.toUpperCase()` at the end of any string variable or litteral

[image]

or same goes for `.toLowerCase()` so first you need to convert to upper case or lower case then compare

```
if (message.content.toUpperCase()==="HELLO")
```

or

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase()==="hello")
```

this is the full code

```
bot.on('message', function(message){
  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === "hello")
  {
    message.reply("hello");
  }
```

Comment: So where would i use that i'm confused would i do something like message.toUpperCase() and would it be before or after the IF statement?

Comment: @GarrettMalan i updated the example with more explanation, please check

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toUpperCase()`

```
bot.on('message', function(message){
  if(message.content.toUpperCase() == "HELLO")
  {
    message.reply("hello");
  }
```